# How can I set selected model with list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller I set the items in the ViewBag:

```
List<ShopItemModel> items = new List<ShopItemModel>();
/* populate my items */
ViewBag.Items = items;
```

So on the cshtml i run thru the list, but how do I connect it so on postback sets the argument of the Post method in the controller?

The CSHTML:

```
@model Models.ShopItemModel

<h2>Webshop</h2>

@foreach( var item in ViewBag.Items)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>@item.Name</p> <!-- List the item name, but not bounded? -->

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { Name = item.Name }) <!-- outputs just "Name", not the items name -->

        <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
    }
}
```

The post version of the method in the controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(ShopItemModel m)
{
    return View();
}
```

But how do I fix this binding? So I fetch the selected item from the list?

Comment: What is it your trying to do? Your not rendering any controls (input, select, textarea) for the model properties in your form so nothing is posted back. And what do you mean by the selected item? How are you 'selecting' an item?

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Name)
    }
}
```

This will produce html controls like this:

```
<input name="ShopItemModel[3].Name"  ...
```

If you're using this in a form, in your controller, iterate over the POSTed model data:

```
foreach (var item in model)
{
    ... do something to each item
}
```

You *can* use a `foreach` loop in the view rather than a `for` loop, example [here](http://jimfrenette.com/2012/11/razor-foreach-loop-with-index/)